# How to change CSS all element don't have class `name` on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I write a filter product by category.

When I click a category, it will add a class `selected` to  element and the background of this category had `selected`.

I think problem at line:

`if (!$filterLinks.hasClass('selected') )`

I want to when user click another

element, all

element should go to background default is `white`.

My HTML structure:

```
<ul id="filters">
    <li> <a class="selected" data-filter="*"></a> All <li>
    <li> <a data-filter=".nokia"></a> Nokia <li>
    <li> <a data-filter=".samsung"></a> Samsung <li>
</ul>
```

And my code:

```
var $filterLinks = $('#filters a');
$filterLinks.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parents('li').css("background", "red");
    if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
        return;
    }

    $filterLinks.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $this.addClass('selected');

    // problem at here, I want when user click another <li> element, 
    // all <li> element should be go to background default is `white`.
    if (!$filterLinks.hasClass('selected') ) {
        $filterLinks.parents('li').css("background", "white");
    }
}
```

Full code at here: https://jsfiddle.net/az2e51c7/

Comment: `$filterLinks.not(".selected")`

Comment: or use ":not(.selected)" as css selector

Comment: is the class on the li or the a element?

Comment: check the console it looks like that isotope script is not loaded and `$container = $('#container')` should be `$container = $('.container')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you use my code:

```
 $("#filters li").click(function()
 {
 $("#filters li").removeClass("selected");
 $(this).addClass("selected");
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, @ajaymalhotra

Comment: Welcome @vanloc :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS

try

```
li > a:not(.selected) {
//add your css here

}
```